Understanding Chern Classes
Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a complex manifold $X$ with curvature form $F_{\nabla}$ of the Chern connection. The Chern classes are defined by:
$$
\det\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}tF_{\nabla} + I_n\right) = \sum_k c_k(F_{\nabla}) t^k,
$$
where
$$
\sum_k c_k(F_{\nabla}) t^k = 1 + i\frac{\operatorname{tr}(F_{\nabla})}{2\pi}t + \ldots,
$$
following the exponential series $\det(A) = \exp(\operatorname{tr}(\ln(A)))$.
Given that $E$ is holomorphic with a Hermitian structure $h$, we can express the curvature as:
$$
F_{\nabla} = \bar{\partial}\bar{H}^{-1}\partial \bar{H},
$$
where $H = h_{ij}$.
Is this the correct way to understand $\operatorname{tr}(F_{\nabla})$?

It is rude and bad form to erase your previous post and comments and repost.

@TedShifrin The previous post had some mistakes, no intention to offend anyone.

Edit the post to correct errors. You may not have been interested in the content of my several comments, but they contained useful and relevant information.

@TedShifrin Editing the previous post would mean I have to delete this one, which have received better reputation than the previous one, so more people maybe tempted to answer my question. I can copy your comments here if you want. If you still think this is wrong, I will happily delete this one and edit the previous one.

Do better copy all the comments here then. I don't want to waste time making the same comments.....

Previous comments: @TedShifrin-"Chern classes are defined for complex bundles on topological spaces that are not manifolds — let alone complex manifolds. Your viewpoint based on Chern connections is overly narrow."
領域展開-"Thank you for your input. For now, I am focusing on understanding Chern classes within the context of Chern connections on complex manifolds. I believe this "narrow" viewpoint is a good starting point."

previous comments: @TedShifrin- "Chern-Weil theory tells you that the cohomology class of
is independent of any choice of connection you use to define the curvature form. The cohomology classes are important in topology and in algebraic geometry: see, for example, the discussion of degeneracy loci in Griffiths/Harris. This is related to the Schubert cycles in Grassmannians and their relation to the Chern classes of the universal bundles."
